# How to stop onclick from firing before ondblclick in JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
    <title> Visibility control </title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <script type = "text/javascript"  src = "showHide.js" >
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action = "">
      <div id = "saturn"  style = "position: relative; 
           visibility: visible;">
        <img src = "../images/saturn.png" 
             alt = "(Pictures of Saturn)" />
      </div>
      <p>
        <br />
        <input type = "button"  value = "Show/Hide"
               onclick = "ShowIMG()" ondblclick = "HideIMG()" />
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the html part. What What I've done here is when the user clicks the button once, a showIMG function is called to show the image. When the user clicks it twice within 3 seconds the hideIMG function is called and the image disappears instead.

```
function ShowIMG() 
{
    dom = document.getElementById("saturn").style;  

    if (dom.visibility == "hidden")
    {
        dom.visibility = "visible";
    }
}

function HideIMG() 
{ 
    var theDelay = 3000;

    setTimeout(function()
    {
        dom = document.getElementById("saturn").style;

        if (dom.visibility == "visible") 
        {
            dom.visibility = "hidden";
        }

    }, theDelay);
}
```

The ondblclick event fires the onclick event first. So it messes with the code.

Comment: Why double click to hide? It doesn't seem very intuitive. Why not click once to show, click again to hide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so different approach to more target what you want here:

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Show/Hide" onclick="ShowIMG()" />
```

JS

```
var timer;
var counter = 0;
function ShowIMG() 
{
    if (counter++ == 0) {
        timer = window.setTimeout(function(){

            dom = document.getElementById("saturn").style;  
            if (counter>1) {
                dom.visibility = "hidden";
            } else {
                dom.visibility = "visible";
            }

            counter = 0;
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

With this solution, a timeout starts when the user clicks and within 3 seconds from then, if he clicks more (meaning at least a second time) then it'll hide `dom`, otherwise (no more clicks) it'll show it.

Depending on the exact behaviour you're expecting here (very unclear), you could reset the timer based on conditions (for example, odd number of clicks before the timer fires) with `clearTimeout`. You could also change the `if (counter>1)` to `if (counter%2==0)`, meaning that an even number of clicks will hide.

Just play with it.

Comment: I'll be trying this out when I get home. I've left now so in about 6 or so hours I'll give you the verdict. So I no longer need the on double click event? Also, any changes to the html doc?

Comment: This one works, although I have no bloody idea what the condition counter++ == 0 means

Comment: it means that i'm testing for `counter == 0` and then I do `counter = counter + 1;`

Answer (score 1):

You can delay the execution of the onclick to see if it actually was a double click. You will lose in responsiveness though:

```
var dble = false;
function ShowIMG() 
{
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        if(!dble){
            dom = document.getElementById("saturn").style;  

            if (dom.visibility == "hidden")
            {
                dom.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
        dble = false;
    }, 500); //this is how long it waits for the double click
}

function HideIMG() 
{ 
    dble = true;

    dom = document.getElementById("saturn").style;

    if (dom.visibility == "visible") 
    {
        dom.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

See the `500` delay in the timeout? This is how long it'll wait (in milliseconds) to see if a double click fires. The shorter the better (for responsiveness) but also the shorter the more risk there is for a double click to happen after anyway.

Comment: You should put that `//comment` outside your code, as it's currently stretching the width of your code block quite a lot

Comment: Good call, changed it.

Comment: Okay so I tried this also but the same issue. Nothing happens.

Comment: Try removing the timeout on your `HideIMG()`. Try it with my solution and Joeytje50's. I'll edit my code

Comment: None worked. It goes on and off at random intervals. I click 4 times it goes off, maybe 5 times it goes off, sometimes it doesn't want to show up again either.

Comment: Try mine again, there was a bug (`dble=false` should be inside the timeout, not outside).

Comment: Okay thanks. So far this has worked the best, but I need it at 3000 for 3 seconds instead of 500 for half a second. I changed it to 3000 and it still works but only if I double click within a second. If I try to click then wait and do the double click around 2.5 seconds it doesn't work and nothing happens

Comment: So do you want an actual double click? Or any rhythm of click as long as it is within 3 seconds?

Comment: Any rhythm of click as long as it is within 3 seconds. That one.

Comment: I posted a new answer for this behavior exactly. Then i believe it answers your question as closely as possible without chatting in longer details. Just play with it to get the exact behavior you have in mind. Could you validate it?

Comment: @FlorianPellet I'm giving you an upvote (A for effort), because you've obviously done as much as you could do with the provided information. OP is just being too unclear in asking the question. I myself am going to call it a night.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the doubleclick delay to 3 seconds, you'd have to basically make the doubleclick mechanism yourself:

```
function ShowIMG() {
    var saturn = document.getElementById("saturn").style;  
    if (!window.clicked) {
        //show image
        saturn.visibility = "visible";

        //remember the user's click
        window.clicked = setTimeout(function() {
            window.clicked = false;
        }, 3000);
    } else if (window.clicked) {
        clearTimeout(window.clicked); //reset
        window.clicked = false;
        saturn.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

with your HTML code being:

```
    <input type="button" value="Show/Hide" onclick="ShowIMG()" />
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4XK5/1/)

This code will show the image when the viewer clicks once on the button, and when they click again within 3 seconds of the first click, the image hides.

If the user clicks twice, and then 2 seconds later they click again, it will show up again as expected from a single click. If the user clicks three times fast, it will not show up, since it is not considered a single click then.

Comment: I've tried it and directly changed the code. But it's still doing the same thing, I click twice within 3 seconds and it does nothing. But if I spam the mouse button quickly, after around the 11th or 12th click it then proceeds to hide.

Comment: The `HideImg` function will only run if you actually doubleclick the element.

Comment: @user3658799 I've updated my question. Is this more like what you were looking for?

Comment: None worked. It goes on and off at random intervals. I click 4 times it goes off, maybe 5 times it goes off, sometimes it doesn't want to show up again either.

Comment: @user3658799 what it currently works with is the following: click once, it shows. Click again after 1 second, it hides. Click again after another second, it shows again. OR: click once, it shows, click again within half a second, it hides. Click again within half a second, it remains hidden. See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4XK5/) for an example of what I mean. I could also make it ignore tripleclicks and just completely reset after a double click.

Comment: @user3658799 please try this updated code. It should work just like you requested

Comment: Everytime I click it goes from visible to hidden and vice versa. so it didn't work

Comment: @user3658799 no it doesn't. Wait more than 3 seconds after it shows up before clicking again, and it'll not hide. That's what you asked for.